# How can I know that a task I started onResume is running?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

If I run an async call `onResume` is there a good way to detect that if the async call is running to not call it again?
Because I am doing a network call using an `AsynTask` in `onResume` of a Fragment and it seems to be called too often

**Update**
THe problem is that when `onResume` is called there are no variables available. So I don't have a valid reference of an async task anymore to check the status.
The code is like:

```
public void onResume()  {  
   AsynTask<Void, Void, String> theTask = new AsyncTask<>() {
   //code to run  
   };
   theTask.execute();  
//code  
}
```

So how am I suppose to do this since I don't have a reference? I mean where should I keep `theTask` in order to be able to cancel it `onResume`?

Comment: @WandMaker:But `onResume` is called when no instance variable of the fragment is available. How am I suppose to call the `getStatus` of the task?

Comment: i just google it which what you probably should do, here is the link http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.Status.html

Comment: @has19:Check my previous comment please

Comment: well show us your code plz

Comment: @has19:Please see updated OP

Comment: @Jim Did not realize that.  Seems tricky now - if your activity has just got recreated, how will the async task be running and how can you check its status?  You may have to think different design - may be use `Service` ?!?!?

Comment: @WandMaker:Yes! That is the problem. `onResume` was the only place (except `onCreateView`) that is guaranteed to be called when we go back to the fragment from another fragment etc and it seems to be called too often.

Comment: @Jim If scenario is going back from one fragment to another, then, you can have a member variable in Fragment class that is reference to AsyncTask and can check status then.  This will not work in case of Actvity being restarted, but that should be rare

Comment: @jim just make thetask public and once onresume is called you check if it is null or not,if null than you make a new asynctask and execute it and if it is not null than you check whether asyntask is running or not

Comment: @has19:Why public if I only check it inside the fragment's `onResume` and I use it only in that fragment?

Comment: @jim that's not my point , i mean make it global in your fragment class

Comment: @WandMaker:What is the best status to check? FINISHED?

Comment: @Jim FINISHED seems right

Answer (score 1):

You can [`getStatus`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#getStatus%28%29) to get the status of the `AsyncTask`. To check if its running you can compare it to [`AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.Status.html).

Comment: But if it is PENDING it means that it is submitted? Why not just check with FINISHED?